# creating functions in for loop to control ToggleButton, problem with late binding (ipywidgets JupyterLab)

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, late-binding

I'm trying to make ToggleButtons for my plot and stumble upon a problem. I created the buttons, no problem:

```
# create buttons
button = []
for i in range(len(expnum)):
    button.append(wg.ToggleButton(value=False, description=expnum[i], tooltip='Click to show/hide', layout=wg.Layout(width='60px', height='30px')))
    button.append(wg.Output())
```

The problem is this part:

```
# control buttons
for i in range(len(expnum)):
    def on_value_change(change):
        with button[i * 2 + 1]:
            plots[i][0].set_visible(change['new'])
    button[i * 2].observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

The problem with the code is (I guess) the late binding problem. It recognizes only the last value (meaning: only in the state of `i == len(expnum)-1`) which is not what I expected. I actually succeeded in making it works like what I expected with the following codes below:

```
# control buttons
def on_value_change(change):
    with button[1]:
        plots[0][0].set_visible(change['new'])
button[0].observe(on_value_change, names='value')    
    
def on_value_change(change):
    with button[3]:
        plots[1][0].set_visible(change['new'])
button[2].observe(on_value_change, names='value')

def on_value_change(change):
    with button[5]:
        plots[2][0].set_visible(change['new'])
button[4].observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

and so on. Currently the number of iteration is still manageable to have it manually written like that, but with increasing amount of data, it is impossible to not using for loop.

I am kind of new to python and I'm pretty sure there must be some kind of simple hack or workaround to make this thing works. I have found some thread that explained about forcing early binding with `def f(i=i):` instead of just `def f():`. But I have no idea how to implement those to my case.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve my problem with for loop? Otherwise a complete new approach is also welcomed.

--- edit ---

This is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as wg
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib widget

expnum = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
t_all = [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 5] ]
V_all = [ [100, 200, 100], [100, 120, 130], [150, 105, 100] ]

# create buttons
button = []
for i in range(len(expnum)):
    button.append(wg.ToggleButton(value=False, description=expnum[i], tooltip='Click to show/hide', layout=wg.Layout(width='60px', height='30px')))
    button.append(wg.Output())
display(HBox(( [button[i] for i in range(len(button))] )) )

# create figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('t [s]')
ax.set_ylabel('V [V]')

plots = []
for i in range(len(t_all)):
    plots.append(ax.plot(t_all[i], V_all[i], visible=False, alpha=0.7))    

# ---------------- The problem starts here --------------------------    
# set visibility of plots
for i in range(len(expnum)):
    def on_value_change(change):
        with button[i * 2 + 1]:
            plots[i][0].set_visible(change['new'])
    button[i * 2].observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

Why does above code (starting from `# set visibility of plots`) doesn't work, while below code works:

```
def on_value_change(change):
    with button[1]:
        plots[0][0].set_visible(change['new'])
button[0].observe(on_value_change, names='value')    
    
def on_value_change(change):
    with button[3]:
        plots[1][0].set_visible(change['new'])
button[2].observe(on_value_change, names='value')

def on_value_change(change):
    with button[5]:
        plots[2][0].set_visible(change['new'])
button[4].observe(on_value_change, names='value')
```

I see no difference in the code below and the code above other than using for loop instead of manually retype the same code over and over.

Comment: Can you please share you full code with imports, and try to mock out any dataframes with a dictionary rather than loading files.

Comment: Hi @ac24 I added my full code with imports in the questions including the csv file that was linked to the data. `try to mock out any dataframes with a dictionary rather than loading files` Pardon me, but what does it mean to mock out any dataframes with a dictionary?

Comment: https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports see the 'Dont post data' section

Comment: @ac24 thanks, just did it accordingly and edited the question.